# cmd.exe: Undo move of files in one file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, move, undo

I ran a batch (`.bat`) file that moves files into a directory, but I forgot to make the folder. Thus, with:

```
move "a.ext" x
move "b.ext" x
move "c.ext" x
```

files "a", "b", and "c" were moved into file "x". How do I get files "a", "b", and "c" back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is any way, short of using your backup copy.

Move would move and then delete original. You have pretty much moved a.ext to x, then replaced it with b.exe, and replaced that again with c.ext.

DOS can be unforgiving. Sorry.

Comment: That seems to be the case since file "x" is 1.75mb where it should be more like 5mb. I'll see if Recuva works.

Comment: Didn't the MOVE prompt you to replace "x" once the first move was complete? It should have asked you to confirm. If you think I've given you the correct answer can you accept it, I'm new and need all the help I can get.

Comment: No, Command Prompt default programs are old and stupid. Newer software such as [FFmpeg prompts "( Y / N )" before overwriting](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Main-options).

Comment: I always make a backup when doing move/cut functions, just in case it all turns to custard. I did a test on my Windows 7 and it certainly does prompt to confirm intentions. Wish I could help you further.

Comment: there are lot of so called undelete utilities, that you can use to scan file system and find those files. And chances are very good if you did not play too much with copying, writing etc. after incident